# X509TrustManager unsafe implementation but no such method is used on the code

Tags: android-security, trustmanager

I got this mail rejecting my new uploaded app on play store

> Your app(s) listed at the end of this email use an unsafe
>   implementation of the interface X509TrustManager. Specifically, the
>   implementation ignores all SSL certificate validation errors when
>   establishing an HTTPS connection to a remote host, thereby making your
>   app vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks.
>
> To properly handle SSL certificate validation, change your code in the
>   checkServerTrusted method of your custom X509TrustManager interface to
>   raise either CertificateException or IllegalArgumentException whenever
>   the certificate presented by the server does not meet your
>   expectations.

While taking a look on the code I found no such method (checkServerTrusted - X509TrustManager). only X509EncodedKeySpec is used for the In-App Billing.

```
package util;


import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.SignatureException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;

public class Security {
    private static final String TAG = "IABUtil/Security";

    private static final String KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM = "RSA";
    private static final String SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM = "SHA1withRSA";


    public static boolean verifyPurchase(String base64PublicKey, String signedData, String signature) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(signedData) || TextUtils.isEmpty(base64PublicKey) ||
                TextUtils.isEmpty(signature)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Purchase verification failed: missing data.");
            return false;
        }

        PublicKey key = Security.generatePublicKey(base64PublicKey);
        return Security.verify(key, signedData, signature);
    }


    public static PublicKey generatePublicKey(String encodedPublicKey) {
        try {
            byte[] decodedKey = Base64.decode(encodedPublicKey);
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM);
            return keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedKey));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid key specification.");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        } catch (Base64DecoderException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Base64 decoding failed.");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }


    public static boolean verify(PublicKey publicKey, String signedData, String signature) {
        Signature sig;
        try {
            sig = Signature.getInstance(SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM);
            sig.initVerify(publicKey);
            sig.update(signedData.getBytes());
            if (!sig.verify(Base64.decode(signature))) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Signature verification failed.");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "NoSuchAlgorithmException.");
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid key specification.");
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Signature exception.");
        } catch (Base64DecoderException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Base64 decoding failed.");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can this code be modified to fix the above issue? Need help to fix it.

Comment: Did you check all your dependencies?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found that Trustmanager was used on mobilecore library. I removed the library cauz' I don't need any more and it's fixed.